# How to change the range in a VBA script?

Tags: excel, vba

I copied a script to unmerge cells and fill in the blanks with the merged values.

This is the original script:

```
Sub UnMergeSameCell()
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.MergeCells Then
        With Rng.MergeArea
            .UnMerge
            .Formula = Rng.Formula
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Where the Range is set by the user selection.

I want to set the range beforehand (selecting all rows and columns) so I don't have to keep manually selecting everything.

I tried:

```
Sub UnMergeSameCell()
'Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set WorkRng = Range("$1:$8")
'Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
'Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.MergeCells Then
        With Rng.MergeArea
            .UnMerge
            .Formula = Rng.Formula
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Which didn't do anything.

Comment: Are there merged cells in that range?  Also, you haven't specified which worksheet to use, are you sure that it is using the right sheet?

Comment: @RBarryYoung  Ha, sorry yes :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ah that's was missing! Do you know how to just select all rows/columns instead of e.g Range("$1:$572") ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.  Are you asking how to select the cells on a sheet if you don't know where they are, or are you asking how to specify the sheet as well as the cells?

Comment: @RBarryYoung How to select all the cells on a sheet if I don't know in advance exactly how many there are?

Comment: Since you are looking for formatted cells and not necessarily just cells with data in them, then you can use `UsedRange` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange)).  Not that if you've formatted any whole columns/rows then it might select the whole virtual sheet which is *huge*.